# Synchronizing data structure

Tags: java, multithreading

What happens when I use a BlockingQueue to transfer an object representing a complex data structure from thread A to thread B. Assuming I don't access the data structure from A anymore after I put it into the queue.

Is that safe? Will the entire data structure be recursively synchronized or just the one object that I put into the queue.
And what if I send an array through the queue?

Comment: Using BlockingQueue it's the access to the object reference is synchronized not the methods of the object. Such that consumer would not pickup the entry until producer finishes setting it into the queue.

Comment: The JVM and CPU support global memory barriers. Once you add a reference safely, everything else visible safely, not just part of the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the entire data structure be recursively synchronized...?

That depends on what you mean by "recursively synchronized."  IMO I wish they had chosen a different name for the `synchronized` keyword.  It does two things:

(1) Mutual exclusion:  No two threads are allowed to synchronize on the same object at the same time.

(2) Memory visibility:  If thread A updates one or more fields and then exits a synchronized block, and then thread B subsequently synchronizes on the *same object*, then thread B will be guaranteed to see the new values that thread A wrote.

That's all that `synchronized` does.

If your thread A updates a complex data structure and then puts a reference to it into a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, then the put/add/offer method should do something equivalent to entering and leaving a synchronized block.  The remove/poll/take method called by your thread B should do the same.  So, as long as thread A doesn't update the structure after calling put()/add()/offer(), then thread B should be able to see every field that thread A changed.

*Every* field that thread A changed:  Fields of the enqueued object, fields of objects that are reachable from the enqueued object, and fields of completely unrelated objects.  Proper synchronization makes *all* of the changes that thread A makes in the heap visible to thread B.  There's nothing "recursive" about it.

So anyway, if that's what you meant by "recursively synchronized", then the answer is yes.